# Existence of a suitable family of symplectomorphisms.

Tags: linear-algebra, symplectic-geometry, symplectic-linear-algebra

In the book by Dusa McDuff and Salamon, there is the following corollary:

> **Corollary 2.4** Suppose that $\omega_t$ is a smooth family of nondegenerate skew-symmetric bilinear forms on $\mathbb{R}^{2n}$
>   depending on a parameter $t$. Then there exists a smooth family of
>   matrices $\Psi_t$ \in $\mathbb{R}^{2n \times 2n}$ such that
>   $\Psi_t^*\omega_t=\omega_0$ for every $t$.
>
> *Proof:* Theorem $2.3$ and Gram-Schmidt.

Theorem $2.3$ is the existence of a symplectic basis on a symplectic linear space $(V,\omega)$.

However, I don't know how we put together this theorem and Gram-Schmidt in order to furnish corollary 2.4. How is this done?